# Installing Linux on Packard bell GN45 (currently using Windows 7)

Tags: software-installation

I have recently purchased a second hand laptop for the sole purpose of installing Linux. I downloaded Ubuntu 16.04, burned the image file to DVD and restarted my laptop with freshly burned DVD in. I pressed F2 and accessed the boot menu, changed the order to CD/DVD and still it just boots up Windows 7. If anyone has any experience with this particular system, please help.

Comment: Just FYI, Linux is not synonymous with Ubuntu. Ubuntu is based on Linux, but there are many other variants (distros) out there, such as Fedora, Debian and RedHat __:-)__.

Comment: So you think I could try another variant?

Comment: Not necessarily. I just wanted to let you know that Linux doesn't mean Ubuntu.

Comment: 1) have you downloaded the right version (32-/64-bit)? -- 2) was the download correct (md5sum)? -- 3) was the dvd burned correct? (maybe try a lower speed) -- 4) or better try a usb, if the laptops supports booting from it. -- maybe some useful further hints/instructions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I have a Dell desktop, and I bought it refurbished, although the CD/DVD rom is there and works, it does not read when I try to use it to boot from it.  I have an external BR drive, and that always works.  The point to my long story is the drive could be bad, and that is why you can't boot from it.

So the answer given about burning a USB memory stick might be the answer.

Chris